# Change link colors of Google Chart Sankey diagram

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

I have a list of lists with `[from, to, value, color]` entries. I want to create a Sankey diagram with it in google charts. Creating a basic Sankey diagram is not difficult, however, I would like to change the link colors based on the RGB values in the list. I read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey) that we can add an optional column role for `style`. So, I tried to add this in different ways:

```
data.addColumn({type: 'string',role: 'style'});
```

Or:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'style');
```

But none of them work. I also tried setting the `color` attribute to `fill-color` but to no avail.  Lastly I also tried to edit the `options` variable at the bottom of the code, since the node and link colors are here also defined. But I'm not sure how to use the lists values here. Simply changing the `colors` list to a list of RGB values does not work, since the order is then not correct (wrong RGB values are assigned to the links). How do I make sure that the links are filled with the RGB value from the 4th element of the lists? The current output of the code can be found below.

```
<html>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <div id="sankey_multiple" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {
        packages: ["sankey"]
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'From');
        data.addColumn('string', 'To');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
        data.addColumn({
          type: 'string',
          role: 'style'
        });
        data.addRows([
          ['C0_1', 'C0_2', 638, 'color: rgb(255, 207, 207)'],
          ['C0_1', 'C1_2', 164, 'color: rgb(255, 130, 130)'],
          ['C1_1', 'C0_2', 123, 'color: rgb(255, 207, 207)'],
          ['C1_1', 'C1_2', 1313, 'color: rgb(255, 130, 130)'],
          ['C0_2', 'C0_3', 555, 'color: rgb(255, 212, 212)'],
          ['C0_2', 'C1_3', 105, 'color: rgb(255, 127, 127)'],
          ['C1_2', 'C0_3', 111, 'color: rgb(255, 212, 212)'],
          ['C1_2', 'C1_3', 1320, 'color: rgb(255, 127, 127)'],
          ['C0_3', 'C0_4', 495, 'color: rgb(255, 217, 217)'],
          ['C0_3', 'C1_4', 80, 'color: rgb(255, 119, 119)'],
          ['C1_3', 'C0_4', 157, 'color: rgb(255, 217, 217)'],
          ['C1_3', 'C1_4', 1223, 'color: rgb(255, 119, 119)'],
          ['C0_4', 'C0_5', 374, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
          ['C0_4', 'C1_5', 32, 'color: rgb(255, 66, 66)'],
          ['C0_4', 'C2_5', 157, 'color: rgb(255, 186, 186)'],
          ['C1_4', 'C0_5', 91, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
          ['C1_4', 'C1_5', 623, 'color: rgb(255, 66, 66)'],
          ['C1_4', 'C2_5', 545, 'color: rgb(255, 186, 186)'],
          ['C0_5', 'C0_6', 299, 'color: rgb(255, 225, 225)'],
          ['C0_5', 'C1_6', 27, 'color: rgb(255, 63, 63)'],
          ['C0_5', 'C2_6', 59, 'color: rgb(255, 170, 170)'],
          ['C1_5', 'C0_6', 13, 'color: rgb(255, 225, 225)'],
          ['C1_5', 'C1_6', 425, 'color: rgb(255, 63, 63)'],
          ['C1_5', 'C2_6', 197, 'color: rgb(255, 170, 170)'],
          ['C2_5', 'C0_6', 136, 'color: rgb(255, 225, 225)'],
          ['C2_5', 'C1_6', 135, 'color: rgb(255, 63, 63)'],
          ['C2_5', 'C2_6', 409, 'color: rgb(255, 170, 170)'],
          ['C0_6', 'C0_7', 273, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
          ['C0_6', 'C1_7', 29, 'color: rgb(255, 62, 62)'],
          ['C0_6', 'C2_7', 62, 'color: rgb(255, 199, 199)'],
          ['C1_6', 'C0_7', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
          ['C1_6', 'C1_7', 440, 'color: rgb(255, 62, 62)'],
          ['C1_6', 'C2_7', 116, 'color: rgb(255, 199, 199)'],
          ['C2_6', 'C0_7', 49, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
          ['C2_6', 'C1_7', 211, 'color: rgb(255, 62, 62)'],
          ['C2_6', 'C2_7', 382, 'color: rgb(255, 199, 199)'],
          ['C0_7', 'C0_8', 239, 'color: rgb(255, 208, 208)'],
          ['C0_7', 'C1_8', 9, 'color: rgb(255, 40, 40)'],
          ['C0_7', 'C2_8', 31, 'color: rgb(255, 192, 192)'],
          ['C1_7', 'C0_8', 39, 'color: rgb(255, 208, 208)'],
          ['C1_7', 'C1_8', 403, 'color: rgb(255, 40, 40)'],
          ['C1_7', 'C2_8', 210, 'color: rgb(255, 192, 192)'],
          ['C2_7', 'C0_8', 77, 'color: rgb(255, 208, 208)'],
          ['C2_7', 'C1_8', 106, 'color: rgb(255, 40, 40)'],
          ['C2_7', 'C2_8', 344, 'color: rgb(255, 192, 192)'],
          ['C0_8', 'C0_9', 222, 'color: rgb(255, 227, 227)'],
          ['C0_8', 'C1_9', 24, 'color: rgb(255, 49, 49)'],
          ['C0_8', 'C2_9', 47, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
          ['C1_8', 'C0_9', 6, 'color: rgb(255, 227, 227)'],
          ['C1_8', 'C1_9', 367, 'color: rgb(255, 49, 49)'],
          ['C1_8', 'C2_9', 110, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
          ['C2_8', 'C0_9', 49, 'color: rgb(255, 227, 227)'],
          ['C2_8', 'C1_9', 147, 'color: rgb(255, 49, 49)'],
          ['C2_8', 'C2_9', 369, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
          ['C0_9', 'C2_10', 24, 'color: rgb(255, 188, 188)'],
          ['C0_9', 'C1_10', 9, 'color: rgb(255, 26, 26)'],
          ['C0_9', 'C0_10', 192, 'color: rgb(255, 204, 204)'],
          ['C1_9', 'C2_10', 156, 'color: rgb(255, 188, 188)'],
          ['C1_9', 'C1_10', 332, 'color: rgb(255, 26, 26)'],
          ['C1_9', 'C0_10', 40, 'color: rgb(255, 204, 204)'],
          ['C2_9', 'C2_10', 340, 'color: rgb(255, 188, 188)'],
          ['C2_9', 'C1_10', 90, 'color: rgb(255, 26, 26)'],
          ['C2_9', 'C0_10', 67, 'color: rgb(255, 204, 204)'],
          ['C2_10', 'C2_11', 297, 'color: rgb(255, 198, 198)'],
          ['C2_10', 'C1_11', 137, 'color: rgb(255, 19, 19)'],
          ['C2_10', 'C0_11', 62, 'color: rgb(255, 237, 237)'],
          ['C1_10', 'C2_11', 75, 'color: rgb(255, 198, 198)'],
          ['C1_10', 'C1_11', 319, 'color: rgb(255, 19, 19)'],
          ['C1_10', 'C0_11', 13, 'color: rgb(255, 237, 237)'],
          ['C0_10', 'C2_11', 27, 'color: rgb(255, 198, 198)'],
          ['C0_10', 'C1_11', 23, 'color: rgb(255, 19, 19)'],
          ['C0_10', 'C0_11', 210, 'color: rgb(255, 237, 237)'],
          ['C2_11', 'C2_12', 247, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
          ['C2_11', 'C1_12', 95, 'color: rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
          ['C2_11', 'C0_12', 43, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
          ['C1_11', 'C2_12', 182, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
          ['C1_11', 'C1_12', 267, 'color: rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
          ['C1_11', 'C0_12', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
          ['C0_11', 'C2_12', 60, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
          ['C0_11', 'C1_12', 9, 'color: rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
          ['C0_11', 'C0_12', 180, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
          ['C2_12', 'C2_13', 261, 'color: rgb(255, 183, 183)'],
          ['C2_12', 'C0_13', 98, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
          ['C2_12', 'C1_13', 107, 'color: rgb(255, 20, 20)'],
          ['C1_12', 'C2_13', 86, 'color: rgb(255, 183, 183)'],
          ['C1_12', 'C0_13', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
          ['C1_12', 'C1_13', 243, 'color: rgb(255, 20, 20)'],
          ['C0_12', 'C2_13', 26, 'color: rgb(255, 183, 183)'],
          ['C0_12', 'C0_13', 166, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
          ['C0_12', 'C1_13', 6, 'color: rgb(255, 20, 20)'],
          ['C2_13', 'C1_14', 69, 'color: rgb(255, 33, 33)'],
          ['C2_13', 'C0_14', 62, 'color: rgb(255, 245, 245)'],
          ['C2_13', 'C2_14', 219, 'color: rgb(255, 142, 142)'],
          ['C0_13', 'C1_14', 13, 'color: rgb(255, 33, 33)'],
          ['C0_13', 'C0_14', 185, 'color: rgb(255, 245, 245)'],
          ['C0_13', 'C2_14', 38, 'color: rgb(255, 142, 142)'],
          ['C1_13', 'C1_14', 201, 'color: rgb(255, 33, 33)'],
          ['C1_13', 'C0_14', 3, 'color: rgb(255, 245, 245)'],
          ['C1_13', 'C2_14', 134, 'color: rgb(255, 142, 142)'],
          ['C1_14', 'C1_15', 261, 'color: rgb(255, 75, 75)'],
          ['C1_14', 'C0_15', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 239, 239)'],
          ['C0_14', 'C1_15', 17, 'color: rgb(255, 75, 75)'],
          ['C0_14', 'C0_15', 196, 'color: rgb(255, 239, 239)'],
          ['C2_14', 'C1_15', 275, 'color: rgb(255, 75, 75)'],
          ['C2_14', 'C0_15', 104, 'color: rgb(255, 239, 239)'],
          ['C1_15', 'C0_16', 67, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
          ['C1_15', 'C1_16', 464, 'color: rgb(255, 68, 68)'],
          ['C0_15', 'C0_16', 254, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
          ['C0_15', 'C1_16', 26, 'color: rgb(255, 68, 68)'],
          ['C0_16', 'C1_17', 36, 'color: rgb(255, 59, 59)'],
          ['C0_16', 'C0_17', 251, 'color: rgb(255, 242, 242)'],
          ['C1_16', 'C1_17', 406, 'color: rgb(255, 59, 59)'],
          ['C1_16', 'C0_17', 61, 'color: rgb(255, 242, 242)'],
          ['C1_17', 'C1_18', 370, 'color: rgb(255, 64, 64)'],
          ['C1_17', 'C0_18', 48, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
          ['C0_17', 'C1_18', 40, 'color: rgb(255, 64, 64)'],
          ['C0_17', 'C0_18', 245, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
          ['C1_18', 'C1_19', 342, 'color: rgb(255, 73, 73)'],
          ['C1_18', 'C0_19', 41, 'color: rgb(255, 250, 250)'],
          ['C0_18', 'C1_19', 43, 'color: rgb(255, 73, 73)'],
          ['C0_18', 'C0_19', 224, 'color: rgb(255, 250, 250)'],
          ['C1_19', 'C0_20', 43, 'color: rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
          ['C1_19', 'C1_20', 323, 'color: rgb(255, 84, 84)'],
          ['C0_19', 'C0_20', 202, 'color: rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
          ['C0_19', 'C1_20', 41, 'color: rgb(255, 84, 84)'],
          ['C0_20', 'C1_21', 37, 'color: rgb(255, 97, 97)'],
          ['C0_20', 'C0_21', 188, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
          ['C1_20', 'C1_21', 290, 'color: rgb(255, 97, 97)'],
          ['C1_20', 'C0_21', 55, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)']
        ]);

        var colors = ['#a6cee3', '#b2df8a', '#fb9a99', '#fdbf6f',
          '#cab2d6', '#ffff99', '#1f78b4', '#33a02c'
        ];

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
          height: 400,
          sankey: {
            node: {
              colors: colors,
              width: 5,
              nodePadding: 1
            },
            link: {
              colorMode: 'gradient',
              colors: colors
            }
          }
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_multiple'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Current output:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I commented a few lines in your code to get the following result.** (I also changed the colors of the first three data rows to red, green, and blue to make it clear the link colors are being read from the list. The other links should be colored as expected from the data rows):

[image]

**I simply commented out part of your chart options that were overriding the styles defined in your rows:**

```
// Set chart options
var options = {
  height: 400,
  sankey: {
    node: {
      colors: colors,
      width: 5,
      nodePadding: 1
    },
    link: {
      // Uncommenting any of these lines overrides the link colors defined in the data above.
      // colorMode: 'gradient',
      // colors: colors
    }
  }
};
```

**Full modified code:**

```
<div id="sankey_multiple" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ["sankey"]
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      role: 'style'
    });
    data.addRows([
      ['C0_1', 'C0_2', 638, 'color: rgb(255, 0, 0)'], // Color changed to red.
      ['C0_1', 'C1_2', 164, 'color: rgb(0, 255, 0)'], // Color changed to green.
      ['C1_1', 'C0_2', 123, 'color: rgb(0, 0, 255)'], // Color changed to blue.
      ['C1_1', 'C1_2', 1313, 'color: rgb(255, 130, 130)'],
      ['C0_2', 'C0_3', 555, 'color: rgb(255, 212, 212)'],
      ['C0_2', 'C1_3', 105, 'color: rgb(255, 127, 127)'],
      ['C1_2', 'C0_3', 111, 'color: rgb(255, 212, 212)'],
      ['C1_2', 'C1_3', 1320, 'color: rgb(255, 127, 127)'],
      ['C0_3', 'C0_4', 495, 'color: rgb(255, 217, 217)'],
      ['C0_3', 'C1_4', 80, 'color: rgb(255, 119, 119)'],
      ['C1_3', 'C0_4', 157, 'color: rgb(255, 217, 217)'],
      ['C1_3', 'C1_4', 1223, 'color: rgb(255, 119, 119)'],
      ['C0_4', 'C0_5', 374, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
      ['C0_4', 'C1_5', 32, 'color: rgb(255, 66, 66)'],
      ['C0_4', 'C2_5', 157, 'color: rgb(255, 186, 186)'],
      ['C1_4', 'C0_5', 91, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
      ['C1_4', 'C1_5', 623, 'color: rgb(255, 66, 66)'],
      ['C1_4', 'C2_5', 545, 'color: rgb(255, 186, 186)'],
      ['C0_5', 'C0_6', 299, 'color: rgb(255, 225, 225)'],
      ['C0_5', 'C1_6', 27, 'color: rgb(255, 63, 63)'],
      ['C0_5', 'C2_6', 59, 'color: rgb(255, 170, 170)'],
      ['C1_5', 'C0_6', 13, 'color: rgb(255, 225, 225)'],
      ['C1_5', 'C1_6', 425, 'color: rgb(255, 63, 63)'],
      ['C1_5', 'C2_6', 197, 'color: rgb(255, 170, 170)'],
      ['C2_5', 'C0_6', 136, 'color: rgb(255, 225, 225)'],
      ['C2_5', 'C1_6', 135, 'color: rgb(255, 63, 63)'],
      ['C2_5', 'C2_6', 409, 'color: rgb(255, 170, 170)'],
      ['C0_6', 'C0_7', 273, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
      ['C0_6', 'C1_7', 29, 'color: rgb(255, 62, 62)'],
      ['C0_6', 'C2_7', 62, 'color: rgb(255, 199, 199)'],
      ['C1_6', 'C0_7', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
      ['C1_6', 'C1_7', 440, 'color: rgb(255, 62, 62)'],
      ['C1_6', 'C2_7', 116, 'color: rgb(255, 199, 199)'],
      ['C2_6', 'C0_7', 49, 'color: rgb(255, 219, 219)'],
      ['C2_6', 'C1_7', 211, 'color: rgb(255, 62, 62)'],
      ['C2_6', 'C2_7', 382, 'color: rgb(255, 199, 199)'],
      ['C0_7', 'C0_8', 239, 'color: rgb(255, 208, 208)'],
      ['C0_7', 'C1_8', 9, 'color: rgb(255, 40, 40)'],
      ['C0_7', 'C2_8', 31, 'color: rgb(255, 192, 192)'],
      ['C1_7', 'C0_8', 39, 'color: rgb(255, 208, 208)'],
      ['C1_7', 'C1_8', 403, 'color: rgb(255, 40, 40)'],
      ['C1_7', 'C2_8', 210, 'color: rgb(255, 192, 192)'],
      ['C2_7', 'C0_8', 77, 'color: rgb(255, 208, 208)'],
      ['C2_7', 'C1_8', 106, 'color: rgb(255, 40, 40)'],
      ['C2_7', 'C2_8', 344, 'color: rgb(255, 192, 192)'],
      ['C0_8', 'C0_9', 222, 'color: rgb(255, 227, 227)'],
      ['C0_8', 'C1_9', 24, 'color: rgb(255, 49, 49)'],
      ['C0_8', 'C2_9', 47, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
      ['C1_8', 'C0_9', 6, 'color: rgb(255, 227, 227)'],
      ['C1_8', 'C1_9', 367, 'color: rgb(255, 49, 49)'],
      ['C1_8', 'C2_9', 110, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
      ['C2_8', 'C0_9', 49, 'color: rgb(255, 227, 227)'],
      ['C2_8', 'C1_9', 147, 'color: rgb(255, 49, 49)'],
      ['C2_8', 'C2_9', 369, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
      ['C0_9', 'C2_10', 24, 'color: rgb(255, 188, 188)'],
      ['C0_9', 'C1_10', 9, 'color: rgb(255, 26, 26)'],
      ['C0_9', 'C0_10', 192, 'color: rgb(255, 204, 204)'],
      ['C1_9', 'C2_10', 156, 'color: rgb(255, 188, 188)'],
      ['C1_9', 'C1_10', 332, 'color: rgb(255, 26, 26)'],
      ['C1_9', 'C0_10', 40, 'color: rgb(255, 204, 204)'],
      ['C2_9', 'C2_10', 340, 'color: rgb(255, 188, 188)'],
      ['C2_9', 'C1_10', 90, 'color: rgb(255, 26, 26)'],
      ['C2_9', 'C0_10', 67, 'color: rgb(255, 204, 204)'],
      ['C2_10', 'C2_11', 297, 'color: rgb(255, 198, 198)'],
      ['C2_10', 'C1_11', 137, 'color: rgb(255, 19, 19)'],
      ['C2_10', 'C0_11', 62, 'color: rgb(255, 237, 237)'],
      ['C1_10', 'C2_11', 75, 'color: rgb(255, 198, 198)'],
      ['C1_10', 'C1_11', 319, 'color: rgb(255, 19, 19)'],
      ['C1_10', 'C0_11', 13, 'color: rgb(255, 237, 237)'],
      ['C0_10', 'C2_11', 27, 'color: rgb(255, 198, 198)'],
      ['C0_10', 'C1_11', 23, 'color: rgb(255, 19, 19)'],
      ['C0_10', 'C0_11', 210, 'color: rgb(255, 237, 237)'],
      ['C2_11', 'C2_12', 247, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
      ['C2_11', 'C1_12', 95, 'color: rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
      ['C2_11', 'C0_12', 43, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
      ['C1_11', 'C2_12', 182, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
      ['C1_11', 'C1_12', 267, 'color: rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
      ['C1_11', 'C0_12', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
      ['C0_11', 'C2_12', 60, 'color: rgb(255, 191, 191)'],
      ['C0_11', 'C1_12', 9, 'color: rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
      ['C0_11', 'C0_12', 180, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
      ['C2_12', 'C2_13', 261, 'color: rgb(255, 183, 183)'],
      ['C2_12', 'C0_13', 98, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
      ['C2_12', 'C1_13', 107, 'color: rgb(255, 20, 20)'],
      ['C1_12', 'C2_13', 86, 'color: rgb(255, 183, 183)'],
      ['C1_12', 'C0_13', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
      ['C1_12', 'C1_13', 243, 'color: rgb(255, 20, 20)'],
      ['C0_12', 'C2_13', 26, 'color: rgb(255, 183, 183)'],
      ['C0_12', 'C0_13', 166, 'color: rgb(255, 226, 226)'],
      ['C0_12', 'C1_13', 6, 'color: rgb(255, 20, 20)'],
      ['C2_13', 'C1_14', 69, 'color: rgb(255, 33, 33)'],
      ['C2_13', 'C0_14', 62, 'color: rgb(255, 245, 245)'],
      ['C2_13', 'C2_14', 219, 'color: rgb(255, 142, 142)'],
      ['C0_13', 'C1_14', 13, 'color: rgb(255, 33, 33)'],
      ['C0_13', 'C0_14', 185, 'color: rgb(255, 245, 245)'],
      ['C0_13', 'C2_14', 38, 'color: rgb(255, 142, 142)'],
      ['C1_13', 'C1_14', 201, 'color: rgb(255, 33, 33)'],
      ['C1_13', 'C0_14', 3, 'color: rgb(255, 245, 245)'],
      ['C1_13', 'C2_14', 134, 'color: rgb(255, 142, 142)'],
      ['C1_14', 'C1_15', 261, 'color: rgb(255, 75, 75)'],
      ['C1_14', 'C0_15', 12, 'color: rgb(255, 239, 239)'],
      ['C0_14', 'C1_15', 17, 'color: rgb(255, 75, 75)'],
      ['C0_14', 'C0_15', 196, 'color: rgb(255, 239, 239)'],
      ['C2_14', 'C1_15', 275, 'color: rgb(255, 75, 75)'],
      ['C2_14', 'C0_15', 104, 'color: rgb(255, 239, 239)'],
      ['C1_15', 'C0_16', 67, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
      ['C1_15', 'C1_16', 464, 'color: rgb(255, 68, 68)'],
      ['C0_15', 'C0_16', 254, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
      ['C0_15', 'C1_16', 26, 'color: rgb(255, 68, 68)'],
      ['C0_16', 'C1_17', 36, 'color: rgb(255, 59, 59)'],
      ['C0_16', 'C0_17', 251, 'color: rgb(255, 242, 242)'],
      ['C1_16', 'C1_17', 406, 'color: rgb(255, 59, 59)'],
      ['C1_16', 'C0_17', 61, 'color: rgb(255, 242, 242)'],
      ['C1_17', 'C1_18', 370, 'color: rgb(255, 64, 64)'],
      ['C1_17', 'C0_18', 48, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
      ['C0_17', 'C1_18', 40, 'color: rgb(255, 64, 64)'],
      ['C0_17', 'C0_18', 245, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
      ['C1_18', 'C1_19', 342, 'color: rgb(255, 73, 73)'],
      ['C1_18', 'C0_19', 41, 'color: rgb(255, 250, 250)'],
      ['C0_18', 'C1_19', 43, 'color: rgb(255, 73, 73)'],
      ['C0_18', 'C0_19', 224, 'color: rgb(255, 250, 250)'],
      ['C1_19', 'C0_20', 43, 'color: rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
      ['C1_19', 'C1_20', 323, 'color: rgb(255, 84, 84)'],
      ['C0_19', 'C0_20', 202, 'color: rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
      ['C0_19', 'C1_20', 41, 'color: rgb(255, 84, 84)'],
      ['C0_20', 'C1_21', 37, 'color: rgb(255, 97, 97)'],
      ['C0_20', 'C0_21', 188, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)'],
      ['C1_20', 'C1_21', 290, 'color: rgb(255, 97, 97)'],
      ['C1_20', 'C0_21', 55, 'color: rgb(255, 241, 241)']
    ]);

    var colors = ['#a6cee3', '#b2df8a', '#fb9a99', '#fdbf6f',
      '#cab2d6', '#ffff99', '#1f78b4', '#33a02c'
    ];

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
      height: 400,
      sankey: {
        node: {
          colors: colors,
          width: 5,
          nodePadding: 1
        },
        link: {
          // Uncommenting these lines overrides the link colors defined in the data above.
          // colorMode: 'gradient',
          // colors: colors
        }
      }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_multiple'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the effort.